# Problema con función para eliminar carpeta PHP

Tags: php, html, post, php8

tengo un problema raro...Hace tiempo cree una función que eliminaba la carpeta que deseaba desde una administración, pero cambie a PHP8 y creo que debe ser por eso elimina más que solo la carpeta.

Ejemplo

ANTES: C:/xampp/htdocs/mi-proyecto/temas/(nombre de la carpeta a eliminar) y lo hacía

Ahora: C:/xampp/htdocs/mi-proyecto/temas/(nombre de la carpeta a eliminar) elimina la carpeta "temas"

Lo que se le pasa como parámetro es la ruta de la carpeta que debe eliminar

La función era

```
   # Función para eliminar carpeta del tema
   function deleteFolder($dir) {
      $files = scandir($dir);
      array_slice($files, 2);
      foreach ($files as $file) {
         $file = "{$dir}/{$file}";
         if (is_dir($file)) {
            $this->deleteFolder($file);
            rmdir($file);
         } else unlink($file);
      }
      rmdir($dir);
   }
```

Luego lo cambie por esta

```
# Función para eliminar carpeta del tema
   function eliminar_tema_carpeta($tema) {
      if(!$opendir = @opendir($tema)) return;
       while (false !== ($archivo = readdir($opendir))) {
          if($archivo != '.' && $archivo != '..') {
            if (!@unlink("{$tema}/{$archivo}")) $this->eliminar_tema_carpeta("{$tema}/{$archivo}");
          }       
       }
       closedir($opendir);
       @rmdir($tema);
   }
```

pero en ambas elimina la carpeta temas, y no entiendo que es lo que puede ser, ya que no hay ninguna instrucción que regrese atrás...

Comment: Depura tu código y podrás ver qué es lo que está ocurriendo. Si aún así no entiendes lo que pasa indica en la pregunta lo que has depurado y con qué resultados. Por depurar aquí me refiero a que imprimas las variables con las que el código trabaja.

Comment: Si has solucionado tu problema puedes responder a tu propia pregunta, no es correcto ponerlo en la misma pregunta

Answer (score 0):

### SOLUCIONADO

Ya he solucionado este problema modifique la función

```
# Función para eliminar carpeta del tema
   function eliminar_tema_carpeta($tema_carpeta) {
    $tema = $tema_carpeta;
      if(!$opendir = opendir($tema)) return;
       while (false !== ($archivo = readdir($opendir))) {
          $fc = "{$tema}/{$archivo}";
          if($archivo != '.' && $archivo != '..') {
            if(is_file($fc)) {
                unlink($fc);
            } else if(is_dir($fc)) {
                $this->eliminar_tema_carpeta($fc);
                rmdir($fc);
            }
          }       
       }
       closedir($opendir);
        rmdir($tema_carpeta);
   }
```